# codeigniter 3.1.3 pagination shows same record

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

i don't understand why this is happening but same row on every page reload shows. I'm new to codeigniter and know basics of php and programming. Thank you for help in advance.

model:

```
class Clanovi_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_clanovi($limit, $offset) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $query = $this->db->get('clan');

        return $query->result();
    }

    public function broji_clanove() {
        return $this->db->count_all('clan');
    }   
}
```

controller:

```
class Clanovi extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        $this->load->model('Clanovi_model');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter5/index.php/clanovi';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->Clanovi_model->broji_clanove();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['clanovi'] = $this->Clanovi_model->get_clanovi($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['paginacija'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('zaglavlje');
        $this->load->view('clanovi', $data);
        $this->load->view('podnozje');
    }
}
```

view:

```
<h2>Članovi</h2>
<hr>
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
<th>Ime</th>
<th>Prezime</th>
<th>Adresa</th>
<th>Korisničko ime</th>
<th>Lozinka</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($clanovi as $clan): ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $clan->ime; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $clan->prezime; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $clan->adresa; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $clan->korisnicko_ime; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $clan->lozinka; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php echo $paginacija; ?>
```

routes:

```
$route['clanovi/(:num)'] = 'clanovi/index/$1';
$route['clanovi'] = 'clanovi';
```

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDVHa.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6DPm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by looking what $this->uri->segment(3); does, and changed value to 2.

```
$data['clanovi'] = $this->Clanovi_model->get_clanovi($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2));
```